# Установка положения jScrollPane java

Tags: java, swing

К списку `fontList` (`jList`), содержащему значения в виде названий шрифтов прикручен jScrollPane. По умолчанию стоит `fontList.setSelectedIndex(20)`. Подскажите как заставить `scrollPane` изначально прокрутиться на выделенное по умолчанию (индекс 20) значение в списке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
fontList.setSelectedIndex(10); // селектим элемент
...
int size = fontList.getModel().getSize(); // получаем количество элементов
int scrollmax = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getMaximum(); // получаем размер скролла
int selected = fontList.getSelectedIndex();
scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar()
            .setValue(scrollmax / size * selected); // ставим скролл на нужную позицию
```

<sub>[Пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544758/how-to-adjust-position-of-scroll-in-the-scrollpane)</sub>

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сработало на отлично! Как раз то, что и было нужно! Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Для `JList` можно использовать такой код:

```
list.ensureIndexIsVisible( list.getSelectedIndex() );
```

Для компонентов swing вообще есть [`JComponent.scrollRectToVisible`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#scrollRectToVisible-java.awt.Rectangle-):

```
int selected = list.getSelectedIndex();
if ( selected != -1 ) { // getCellBounds возвращает null для значений вне списка
    list.scrollRectToVisible( list.getCellBounds( selected, selected ) );
}
```

Код прокрутит родительскую `JScrollPane` так, чтобы сделать первую выбранную строку видимой (строка будет внизу панели прокрутки).

- [Руководство по ScrollPane от Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)